# $NTime(2^n) \subseteq NSpace(n^k)$ implies $EXP = PSPACE$?

Tags: complexity-theory

Assume $NTime(2^n) \subseteq  NSpace(n^k)$, for some fixed $k$. Is it possible to imply that $EXP = PSPACE$? and what about $NEXP = PSPACE$? It seems the answer might be YES, because this question seems to be equivalent to the open question $EXP=PSPACE$?
Can it be shown using some padding argument?

Comment: Are you aware of [Savitch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch's_theorem)?

Comment: I can see why it leads to NEXP=PSPACE. But how Savitch theorem is related to EXP=PSPACE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\let\c\mathrm$The assumption
$$\c{NTIME}(2^n)\subseteq\c{NSPACE}(n^k)\tag1$$
indeed implies
$$\c{PSPACE=EXP=NEXP}$$
by a simple padding argument. The inclusions
$$\c{PSPACE\subseteq EXP\subseteq NEXP}$$
hold unconditionally. In order to show $\c{NEXP\subseteq PSPACE}$, take an arbitrary language $L\in\c{NEXP}$, and let $c$ be such that $L\in\c{NTIME}(2^{n^c})$. Then the language
$$L'=\{(w,1^n):w\in L,n\ge|w|^c\}$$
is in $\c{NTIME}(2^n)$, hence
$$L'\in\c{NSPACE}(n^k)\subseteq\c{DSPACE}(n^{2k})\subseteq\c{PSPACE}$$
by (1) and Savitch’s theorem. Since $L$ is polynomial-time reducible to $L'$ by means of the function $w\mapsto(w,1^{|w|^c})$, it follows that $L\in\c{PSPACE}$, too.